# Inventor parts that move in sub-assembly won't move in main assembly

Tags: cad, autodesk-inventor

So suppose I have 4 files.

- Part 1
- Part 2
- Sub-assembly
- Assembly

Now in sub-assembly, part1 and part 2 are "connected" to each other and there is an articulation.

Everything works well until I place my sub-assembly in my main assembly. When I do that, part1 and part 2 can't "move" anymore. How do I solve that problem??